# EntityManager: Setting LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE seems not to do Locking

Tags: jpa, locking, java-ee-7

I am devlopping a Java EE Application running on Wildfly 8.1.0 using JPA (Hibernate) and Postgresql. I have incoming REST-requests, which can, of courese income in parallel, asynchronously.

I have a REST-function "decrement", which shall beside other things decrement a value in the Database for a given amount. So this function needs to
 1) retrieve a dataset (with EntityManager)
 2) Read the value member from the Entity
 3) Decrement this value
 4) Store it back in the Entity
 5) Save this dataset (em.merge)

I need a locking mechanism to lock reading my value as long as a previous read value is not decremented and stored back (otherwise two parallel requests will read the same value, decrement it and store it back)
So I placed `em.lock(<entity>, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` between step 1) and 2).

However, it does not seem to solve my inconsistence problem I do have. If I run some parallel test loops, which requests my decrement method (over REST) I can see that I have not that much decrements as I have calls - even with em.lock.

Well, if I do not set `<property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="1000"/>` in `persistence.xml`, I get a lot of `LockTimeoutExceptions` after starting a second test loop, which showes, that locks are set.

What could be wrong? - Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: and what is the SQL invoked after you set this lock? when using the same EntityManager

Comment: I will look next Monday at work, what is traced out. However, I thought that these kind of locks are managed inside JPA manager (Hibernate) and do not invoke any SQL.

Comment: the logical way to do a PESSIMISTIC lock is to add "FOR UPDATE" on the end of a SELECT ... in the datastore

Comment: I will try that. But why does the other way not work? I think there must be a reason and since I am not yet an expert of JPA, I do hope that someone can point me to it.

Comment: what "other way"? The JPA implementation chooses how it implements PESSIMISTIC txns, and as I already said, the most logical way would be for Hibernate to add that to statements (hence why I asked the SQL statement being issued). In fact you can see this exact thing in their manual https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html#d0e2462

Comment: With "other way" I mean EntityManager.lock(<entity>, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) as I described in the first post. I probably missunderstood you - I thought you mean that I should do the "FOR UPDATE" on the end of SELECT in e.g. a special named query. But if I understand correctly, you mean that this should be what hibernate does. So this is probably the mistake I make: I set the lock after executing the named query [as I wrote - between step 1) and 2)] - should I set it before? - Hmm, I don't think so because the Entity would be undefined before loading it... I check your link, thanks!

Comment: OK. I am back. Instead of executing em.lock, I created now a named query setting qry.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE). This will cause the SELECT .. FOR UPDATE. But the inconsistence still remains. Does it have something to do with the EntityManager, because it is not thread safe? - But I inject in every REST Request a new Object with the EntityManager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I found a simple solution for this problem: I do the decrement in the query itself, e.g.

```
UPDATE Account a SET a.balance = a.balance - :value WHERE a = :account
```

Of course, we can also do Limit checking, if needed e.g. make sure the balance is never negative...

```
UPDATE Account a SET a.balance = a.balance - :value WHERE a = :account AND a.balance >= :value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optimistic lock:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  @Version
  private long optimisticLockField; //will be under the management of the lock, do not modify

  ... other entity fields

}
```

Comment: Well, Optimistic Locking is not that good for this situation because update collisions are expected. So I need a lock mechanism exactly like PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in combination with a timeout > 0. If I would use optimistic locking, I would need to handle the exception, which would be raised all the time and then? - I must just try to repeat the "transaction" (read value, decrement, store).